# How to display "ALL" the nested documents in an object in separate rows from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a nested object in the following form:

```
{
  "name": "Multi G. Enre",
  "books": [
    {
      "name": "Guns and lasers",
      "genre": "scifi",
      "publisher": "orbit"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dead in the night",
      "genre": "thriller",
      "publisher": "penguin"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following JSON query for the above document:

```
{
 "query": {
  "filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "books",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
            "and": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "books.publisher": "penguin"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "books.genre": "thriller"
                }
               }
             ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

So,I would like to see the second nested document i.e. "Dead in the night" as the result but, for anything I search only the first document i.e. "Guns and lasers" is displayed in the table in elasticsearch head plugin.
So, is there any way I can display the nested documents separately based on the search query and not just the first document?
I'm new to elasticsearch,so would appreciate any type of responses. THANKYOU!

Comment: It's a [known shortcoming](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/issues/53) of the head plugin, it doesn't mean your query is wrong. Now maybe there's a way using [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-inner-hits.html)

Comment: @Val   Thankyou so much.It worked. :) the nested inner document that is
actually matched is returned along with the first document. But there is
just one question, is there any way i can return just the matched nested 
inner document and nothing else? But yes, thanx a lot again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-inner-hits.html) in your query.

Moreover, if you want to only retrieve the matching nested document and nothing else, you can add `"_source":["books"]` to your query and only the matching nested books will be returned, nothing else.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You can add `"_source": false` and the top-level document will not be returned. Only the nested matching document.

Comment: I tried this out . I used "_source":["books"] at the beginning of my query. But,this also returns exactly the same result as it returned when i used only the "inner_hits" i.e the matched nested document along with the first document.

Comment: Thankyou so much !! Now, this works pretty fine :) Only the nested matching document is being returned.. Thanks a lot Val  !!! :)